Why are we reminded that Mephiboshet is cripple?
In 2 Samuel 4 we (the reader) are told that Mephiboshet is cripple. In 2 Samuel 9:3 David is told that Mephiboshet is cripple. Then again in verse 13 it once again states that Mephiboshet was lame in both feet. I have not found any commentaries which explain this redundant statement.
I would like to know why the text in verse 13 once again stresses that Mephiboshet was lame in both feet.

According to Steinsaltz: This disability has already been mentioned (4:4, 9:3); it is reiterated in explanation of why Mefivoshet was not especially active. The observation is also important for the continuation of the story of Mefivoshet below (see 16:1–4, 19:25–31).
